# How to build CodeCompileUnit from source code?

Tags: c#, codedom

How to build CodeCompileUnit from source code?

What is the best way to parse a C# source code(s)?

Is CodeCompileUnit a correct selection? and howto?

Thanks

Comment: From your question it is not really what you want to achive... do you need to compile some C# code and then run it and/or save it (as .dll or .exe) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got that backwards, CodeCompileUnit is there to *generate* source code.  If you already have the source code then you only need a class that inherits CodeDomProvider to compile the code.  Like Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider or Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider.

There are some odds that you are asking about *parsing* an existing source code file.  That's what the System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeParser was intended to do.  There are no existing concrete implementations of that abstract class, there will never be any.  This [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20101114123211/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/16/396929.aspx) explains why.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with CodeSnippetCompileUnit which is a subclass of CodeCompileUnit:

```
string source = @"
using System;
namespace SomeNamespace 
{
  public class Class0
  {     
  }
}";

var csu0 = new CodeSnippetCompileUnit(curSource);
```

Additional Info:

If you have multiple units you can put them together to generate an assembly:

```
CodeDomProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(new CompilerParameters(), csu0, csu1 /*arbitrary number*/);
```

Of course it it possible that classes from all of these CodeSnippetCompileUnit reference each other.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 3):

Your question is kind of vague. Are you looking for a tutorial? Do you have a specific task you are trying to implement? Specific questions are the essence of Stackoverflow. That aside, I'll just give you some places that may be helpful for starting out:

- [MSDN documentation on CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx)
- [Dynamic Code Integration with CodeDom](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CodeDomDelegates.aspx)
- [CodeDOM Assistant](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/codedom_assistant.aspx)